# Retrofit - I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed

Tags: android, web-services, rest, retrofit

I'm trying to make a simple REST request with Retrofit and i'm getting a lot of GC errors. I really don't know how to fix it. I tried to put more memory on emulator but the problem still happens. when make sync call `Response<List<User>> response = usersCall.execute();`
following exception

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
     android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Cause by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:831)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.read(TypeAdapters.java:422)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.read(TypeAdapters.java:410)
at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:116)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
```

and sync call using pojo model `Response<List<User>> response = usersCall.execute();` then

```
04-09 07:37:23.897 13396-13411/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
04-09 07:37:23.897 13396-13411/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3104(48KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 7.520ms total 194.127ms
04-09 07:37:23.897 13396-13396/? I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 182.909ms for cause Alloc
04-09 07:37:23.929 13396-13411/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 128(5KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 8.237ms total 31.761ms
04-09 07:37:23.929 13396-13396/? I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 18.171ms for cause Alloc
04-09 07:37:24.130 13396-13411/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
04-09 07:37:24.130 13396-13411/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5784(90KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 9.388ms total 200.412ms
04-09 07:37:24.130 13396-13396/? I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 200.758ms for cause Alloc
04-09 07:37:24.158 13396-13411/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1710(34KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 6.897ms total 27.286ms
04-09 07:37:24.158 13396-13396/? I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 18.297ms for cause Alloc
04-09 07:37:24.346 13396-13396/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
04-09 07:37:24.346 13396-13396/? I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2092(33KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 5.943ms total 188.191ms
04-09 07:37:24.370 13396-13396/? I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 8.501ms total 23.440ms
04-09 07:37:24.566 13396-13396/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
04-09 07:37:24.566 13396-13396/? I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 6.105ms total 195.296ms
04-09 07:37:24.566 13396-13411/? I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 395.241ms for cause Background
04-09 07:37:24.598 13396-13411/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 6.138ms total 29.195ms
04-09 07:37:24.598 13396-13396/? I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 29.063ms for cause Alloc
04-09 07:37:24.775 13396-13396/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
04-09 07:37:24.775 13396-13396/? I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 16(56KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(54KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 6.803ms total 177.429ms
```

My code:

```
Gson gson =
                new GsonBuilder()
                        .registerTypeAdapter(Usuario.class, new UsuarioDeserializer())
                        .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new CustomDateDeserializer())
                        .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ConstantesUtil.URL_BASE)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        UsuariosAPI usuarioApi = retrofit.create(UsuariosAPI.class);

        Usuario usuario = new Usuario(login, senha);

        Call<List<Usuario>> usuarios = usuarioApi.getUsuarios(usuario);

        usuarios.enqueue(new Callback<List<Usuario>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Usuario>> call, Response<List<Usuario>> response) {
                List<Usuario> usuarios = response.body();

                for (Usuario u: usuarios) {
                    Log.i(TAG, u.getNome());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Usuario>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: None of those are errors. `I/` is for information severity. The messages are because you are nearly out of heap space. Whatever you are doing to consume the heap space is happening before the LogCat lines that you show.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But I need to know why using the retrofit in my aplication i got this kind of alerts.

Comment: Most likely, Retrofit has nothing to do with it. As I noted, you are nearly out of heap space, and whatever you are doing to consume the heap space is happening before the LogCat lines that you show.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this problem (infinate GC loop) happens when the model ("Usuario" in your case) have a member variable which causes serialization issue.

```
public class Usuario {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;

    // the following will cause infinite loop of GC
    public TextView problemView;

    // use transient keyword will solve the problem in GC infinite loop
    private transient TextView okView;
}
```

Comment: what to do if we have JsonObject with retrofit call?@Desmond Lua

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel I have no experience with JsonObject using Retrofit. Why not use Gson with Retrofit call?

Comment: i am already using Gson with Retrofit call, but still have problem of infinite GC loop. how can i fix it?

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel do post a new question with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove any bytes array and Drawable from your pojo class or make it transient.
Enjoy